# Can Kibana visualizations aggregate by a meta field such as _size?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'd like to visualize how our average elasticsearch document size is changing over time.

1. We use ElasticSearch v7.1. We use the AWS ElasticSearch service and the [Mapper Size Plugin is installed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-supported-plugins.html).
2. I enabled the `_size` field on my index. [ref](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/mapper-size-usage.html)
3. In Kibana "Discover" I can find small documents using: `_size: <900`

   - Or I can query from the command line: `curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -s http://es.example.com/logstash-2019.10.17/_search -d '{"query": {"range": {"_size": { "lt": 900 }}}}' | jq .`

Now I want to create a Kibana visualization, for example a date histogram with the median `_size`, **but Kibana "*Visualize*" won't let me select `_size` as the aggregation field**. Is there a way to visualize the size of documents?

---

_size is a "[meta-field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-fields.html)".

> `_size`
>   The size of the `_source` field in bytes, provided by the [mapper-size plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/7.4/mapper-size.html).

Maybe "meta fields" aren't supported in Kibana?

I can aggregate by `_size` when not using Kibana "Visualize":

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -s http://es.example.com/logstash-2019.10.17/_search -d '{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "_size": {
        "gt": 10
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "sizes": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_size",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_size": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}' | jq .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question is old but looks not answered. The solution is:

- go to Kibana Index Patterns
- search and edit the one that you use in Kibana to retrieve data from Elasticsearch index (e.g. logstash-*)
- edit --> Add field

  - use **emit(doc['_size'].value)** as a **value**
  - use **Bytes** as a **format**
- save it

Now the _size value should be available as any other (_source) field at your Kibana visualizations/dashboards etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you go in Kibana to `Management`->`Elasticsearch index management` you can see for specific index that:

[image]

Some fields does not have `Aggretable` on.
Check other fields and see that they have circle in this column.
And that's the reason why Kibana `Visualize` won't let you select `_size` as the `aggregation field`.

Maybe you could use https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/scripted-fields.html
somehow to make it work by making additional field, if `Kibana` would allow you to use `_size` field inside of a script and that field would be `Aggretable` in a sense i mentioned earlier.

Comment: Thanks for your help. For me, the `_size` field doesn't show up in index field list. Maybe because it's a meta field? Although `_index`,`_type`,`_id` and `_score` shows up and they are also meta fields. `_field_names` doesn't show either.

Comment: @Tom As you mentioned the meta fields are listed in here. Try using `refresh` option (https://imgur.com/a/Cm48Itx) if it is new added field it does not have to show immediately.